# Linear Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence:

2; 5; 8;...

Prove that it does not consist of terms that are perfect squares.

I found the general formula which is Tn$=$3n-1, but I don't know what to do next. I also said:

let $k^2$ $=$3n-1

Thus 3 divides $k^2$+1, this was the first part of my proof.I was hoping to achieve a contradiction if possible, I don't know how that might help me.

Comment: $$a\equiv0,\pm1\pmod3\implies a^2\equiv0,1\not\equiv-1$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, what's a and why are you taking it modulo 3? Is there a solution using only algebra and not modular arithmetic.

Comment: Modular arithmetic **is** algebra, too.

Comment: My teacher won't accept a solution where I used modular arithmetic, I tried proving that the terns like the perfect squares are not congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4, and he said I shouldn't use modular arithmetic.